# Pakistani traveling to Bangalore (India) on business visit

Tags: uk, india, pakistani-citizens, pakistan

I live in the UK and work for a Big 4 consulting firm. I'm supposed to make a trip to Bangalore but I hold a Pakistani passport, so not too sure if there are still issues with Pakistanis in India.

I would really love to go, but if it turns out to be too much of a hassle (even when going back to Pakistan) I'd rather not even start on it. I'm hoping to hear from someone with first hand experience.

Answer (score 4):

No first hand experience, but I can tell you that **yes**, getting the Indian visa as a citizen of Pakistan will be a *major* hassle.  The [Indian High Commission in London](https://www.hcilondon.in/pages.php?id=28) is not very informative, but the [Consulate General in Toronto](http://www.cgitoronto.ca/content/pakistani-nationals-and-persons-pakistani-origin) has a good page that outlines the process:

> **Pakistani Citizen**
>
> - Please click on the link
>     http://www.india.org.pk/Sponsor%20Certificate.pdf for Sponsorship
>     Certificate.  The sponsor in India would have to download this
>     Sponsorship Certificate and get it duly attested by one of the Indian
>     authorities as mentioned in the Certificate.  It should then be sent
>     by fax/e-mail or post by the Sponsor in India to the applicant. The
>     details contained in the Sponsorship Form will be used by the
>     applicant to complete the online Visa Application Form.
> - Fill in online visa application form at http://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/. Take a print out  of the visa
>     application, paste a photograph and put your signatures at the places
>     marked on application at its first and the second page.

In addition, application times are quoted as 7-8 weeks by the High Commission in London, and [per anecdotal evidence](http://blogs.tribune.com.pk/story/27209/once-youre-pakistani-there-is-no-going-back-to-india/), visa denial rates are high.

That said, if you have a corporate sponsor and a solid reason to go, I doubt they would deny you the visa -- you will just need to start the paperwork *very* early.